# How to setup Guzzle 3 for sendgrid php without composer

Tags: php, require, guzzle

In my PHP webapplication I like to migrate from mandrill to sendgrid for transaction emails.

I added the sendgrid php folder to my application like so:

```
require_once DOCROOT . 'vendor' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'sendgrid-php' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR  . 'sendgrid-php.php';
```

But when I know try to use sendgrid, I get the error, that I need guzzle:

```
Class 'Guzzle\Http\Client' not found
```

So now I need to add guzzle 3 (because sendgrid is still relying on guzzle 3) to my webapp. But guzzle 3 does not have a simple file that autoloads all other files, so how to I integrate into my webapp?

Comment: I just never worked with it and have not time right now to dive into it.

Answer (score 0):

now im using `"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.2"` , and it's worked when

```
use Guzzle\Http\Client
```